# Android Market Error -17 & Missing-yet-Useable Camera: Has anyone else encountered this and what can be done?

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-2.1-eclair

**The Problem: Background Information**

I'm writing an application for a client that is to work with software called "Layar." When trying to install this software from the Android Market I get the following: "Installation error; Unknown reason -17." I've scoured the web with a co-worker for information and a solution but have found nothing of use.

**Hardware Being Used**

I'm developing the application for several HTC Sapphire 32B's (HTC Magic). The phones are currently running a custom Android operating system. The OS - as far as I am aware - is "custom" only due to a modification in the normal operation of Bluetooth. **EDIT:** The OS of the phones is Android 2.1.

**Where stackoverflow Can Help**

Here's the relevant output while trying to download the program (edited to remove unnecessary lines):

```
D/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.AssetDownloader.downloadAndInstall(): Initiating Download for 1 applications.
I/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.util.DownloadManagerUtil.enqueueDownload(): Enqueue for download com.android.vending.util.DownloadManagerUtil$Request@43b942c8
I/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.AssetDownloader.startDownload(): Download request row inserted at content://downloads/download/19
D/dalvikvm(   75): GC freed 25607 objects / 1316336 bytes in 589ms
D/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.api.LocalAssetDatabase.notifyListener(): -1629133212261177266 / DOWNLOADING
D/dalvikvm( 2286): GC freed 4445 objects / 308864 bytes in 246ms
D/dalvikvm(  178): GC freed 7430 objects / 403216 bytes in 458ms
D/OpenSSLSessionImpl(  178): Freeing OpenSSL session
D/dalvikvm(  178): GC freed 1124 objects / 55112 bytes in 362ms
D/ddm-heap( 2329): Got feature list request
I/ActivityThread( 2329): Publishing provider com.google.android.gmail.SuggestionProvider: com.google.android.gm.SuggestionsProvider
I/ActivityThread( 2329): Publishing provider com.google.android.gm.attachmentspreviews: com.google.android.gm.AttachmentPreviewProvider
I/ActivityManager(   75): Process com.android.browser (pid 1224) has died.
D/dalvikvm( 2286): threadid=23 wakeup: interrupted
I/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.AssetDownloader$DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver$DownloadManagerService.startNextDownload(): Found Paused URI null
I/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.AssetDownloader$DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver$DownloadManagerService.startNextDownload(): No more paused downloads.
D/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.AssetDownloader$DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver$DownloadManagerService.handleDownloadCompletedAction(): Got a download completed intent.
D/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.AssetDownloader$DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver$DownloadManagerService.installFromUri(): Calling install uri=content://downloads/download/19 src=null assetId=-1629133212261177266 name=Layar last=TRUE
D/dalvikvm( 1849): GC freed 10970 objects / 628040 bytes in 400ms
D/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.api.LocalAssetDatabase.notifyListener(): -1629133212261177266 / INSTALLING
D/PackageParser(   75): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl48148.tmp
D/dalvikvm(   75): GC freed 14645 objects / 1016520 bytes in 296ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(   75): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.715MB for 88948-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(   75): GC freed 402 objects / 62296 bytes in 269ms
D/dalvikvm(   75): GC freed 13251 objects / 892840 bytes in 272ms
D/dalvikvm( 2286): GC freed 6457 objects / 439400 bytes in 171ms
E/PackageManager(   75): Package com.layar requires unavailable feature android.hardware.camera; failing!
W/PackageManager(   75): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.layar.apk
D/dalvikvm(   75): GC freed 22681 objects / 975952 bytes in 317ms
D/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.api.LocalAssetDatabase.notifyListener(): -1629133212261177266 / INSTALL_FAILED
D/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.VendingNotificationManager.showNotification(): Showing notification: [AssetID=-1629133212261177266, NotificationID=1229128979, Title=Layar, Message=Installation unsuccessful.]
I/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.AssetDownloader$DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver$MyPackageInstallObserver.packageInstalled(): Package install from content://downloads/download/19 failed: Unknown reason -17
```

The biggest things I can see are these:

```
E/PackageManager(   75): Package com.layar requires unavailable feature android.hardware.camera; failing!
I/vending ( 1849): com.android.vending.AssetDownloader$DownloadManagerBroadcastReceiver$MyPackageInstallObserver.packageInstalled(): Package install from content://downloads/download/19 failed: Unknown reason -17
```

However, the camera *is* available and *is* usable. Does anyone know what might be causing this? Is the error number -17 related to the camera issue? Has anyone else even encountered this? Whatever the case, thank you for your time and thanks in advance if you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is to download the app to a non-custom rom device and see what happens here. Maybe the custom rom broke hardware reporting in some way.

Comment: If I had a device running the same version of the OS (i.e., 2.1) I would. I only have a standard 2.2 HTC Incredible S available for use right now. As that introduces two new conditions (e.g., different hardware, different OS) I can't say that if the problem does not reappear on that phone that my solution is to use a standard version of 2.1. That being said, I'll try to acquire one and narrow down the problem. It could very well be something to do with the custom OS if the maker introduced a bug to camera-relevant code that I am unaware of.

Comment: Well in any case it is worth a try even with these really different conditions : If the bugs appear as well on a non-modded, different os/hardware, then you know it is not due to the modded OS and that's a start :)

Comment: But the pre-requisite to debug this kind of problem is to get your hands on the very device your coding for. And if you want to be thorough in your testing you should have this device and be able to switch from the modded rom to the official rom. Or you'll never know for sure what is happening.

Comment: Agreed. The program was tried on the 2.2; it worked. I'm looking for a standard 2.1 as we speak.

Comment: After talking to the man who modified the ROM I was told that the camera driver had to be custom installed by us and was not a perfect fit. While I am still trying to acquire a standard 2.1, this _appears_ to be the cause of the issue. I'll mark this as solved and will update the question if this is not the case.